# Showing $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\frac1{ij}=\sum_{i=1}^n(\sum_{j=1}^i+\sum_{j=i}^n)\frac{1}{ij}-\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{i^2}$

Tags: summation

I was reading *Almost Impossible Integrals* by Cornel, where I encountered this manipulation

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n \dfrac{1}{ij}= \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\sum_{j=1}^i+\sum_{j=i}^n\right)\dfrac{1}{ij}-\sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac{1}{i^2}$$

I am new to such manipulations, and didn't understand how this works. I know the basics symmetry of summand, but can't deduce this.

Can you please help me understanding this?

Also, after this step, he writes

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\sum_{j=1}^i+\sum_{j=i}^n\right)\dfrac{1}{ij} = 2\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^i \dfrac{1}{ij}$$

How does this happen?

Comment: you are adding and subtracting the case $j=i$ in the inner sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$j=i$ is used twice.

$\displaystyle \left(\sum_{j=1}^i+\sum_{j=i}^n\right)\frac1{ij}=\left(\sum_{j=1}^i+\sum_{j=i+1}^n\right)\frac1{ij}+\frac1{i^2}=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac1{ij}+\frac1{i^2}$

For the second step, we have

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i}^na_{i,j}&=\sum_{i=1}^n(a_{i,i}+a_{i,i+1}+a_{i,i+2}+\cdots+a_{i,n})\\
&=(a_{1,1}+a_{1,2}+a_{1,3}+\cdots+a_{1,n})\\
&\qquad+(a_{2,2}+a_{2,3}+a_{2,4}+\cdots+a_{2,n})\\
&\qquad+(a_{3,3}+a_{3,4}+a_{3,5}+\cdots+a_{3,n})\\
&\qquad+\cdots\\
&\qquad+(a_{n-1,n-1}+a_{n-1,n})\\
&\qquad+a_{n,n}\\
&=a_{1,1}\\
&\qquad+(a_{1,2}+a_{2,2})\\
&\qquad+(a_{1,3}+a_{2,3}+a_{3,3})\\
&\qquad+\cdots\\
&\qquad+(a_{1,n-1}+a_{2,n-1}+a_{3,n-1}+\cdots+a_{n-1,n-1})\\
&\qquad+(a_{1,n}+a_{2,n}+a_{3,n}+\cdots+a_{n-1,n}+a_{n,n})\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n(a_{1,j}+a_{2,j}+\cdots+a_{j,j})\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^ja_{i,j}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^ia_{j,i}
\end{align*}

[image]

Comment: Ok, I got it. It is just what the comment suggested. Thanks.

Comment: Please amend your question to include the next step.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please add the required steps in your answer.

Comment: Not exactly. But there are some mistakes. Amended now.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\sum_{i=1}^j $ instead of $ \sum_{i=1}^i$?

Comment: yes. lot of mistakes

Comment: The previous way of first summing with index $i$ was also viable, but no problem.